# How to remove a Namespace before sending a SOAP request by PHP?

Tags: php, soap, namespaces

I am having a SOAP request which goes like

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns2:get>
<ns2:arg0>
<ns1:type xsi:type="ns1:Type">
.....
</ns1:type>
</ns2:arg0>
</ns2:get>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

currently I am getting error saying that, 'type is not created' because of the namespace in arg0, I guess the Namespace is coming because the previous node has the same namespace and the child is not suppose to go with the same namespace, following is the expected request by my WSDL.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns2:get>
<arg0>
<ns1:type xsi:type="ns1:Type">
.....
</ns1:type>
<arg0>
</ns2:get>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Please brief me, how to remove a namespace before sending the request. I am using stdClass and soapVar() method to create the arg0 variable.